# Google analytics on my React app with firebase SDK

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I used Google Analytics a lot for many sites...

I'm just releasing a first app with Firebase (Firestore + Firebase SDK with reactjs).

Then, I activated GA from my Firebase dashboard... but I cannot see any activity !

[image]

I probably need not to add plugin like "autotrack" ?

```
import 'autotrack';
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

It's not clear because, it's impossible to find out the track ID (UA-XXXXX-Y) from my dashboard !

**Do I really need it ? Where can I find it ?** 
[image]

Comment: I'm having this same issue

Comment: Did you work it out?

Comment: Hi Chris, I posted an answer ;)

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68504289/4185100

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did't correctly initialized Analytics...
With firebase it's not a **track ID** but a **measurementId**

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/analytics';

app.initializeApp({
   //other config
  measurementId : process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  appId : process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_ID
})

//put inside your constructor
app.analytics()
```

This will solve the following error:

> Error: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.analytics is
> not a function react

Documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web

Comment: that worked! If anyone else gets the following error, to uninstall and reinstall the package ypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.analytics is not a function react

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer should be corrected like this:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/analytics';

app.initializeApp({
   //other config
  measurementId : process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  appId : process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_ID
})

//put inside your constructor
app.analytics()
```

This will solve the following error:

> Error: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.analytics is
> not a function react

Answer (score 1):

My issue was the same as listed above:

`Error: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.analytics is not a function react`

But the resolution was that I forgot to import the analytics module: `import 'firebase/analytics';`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript:

```
// On index.tsx
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { initializeAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';

const firebaseConfig = {
 ... your config object ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
initializeAnalytics(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase gone through a lot of new updates. Change imports like this;

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/analytics';
```