# How to get the measurementId from the Firebase config?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-firebase, firebase-cli

To play with *Google Analytics* for Web based projects on Firebase we need to use either the Firebase reserved URLs or to copy/update the Firebase config object as the documentation states [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web#add_the_sdk_to_your_app).

I am using the following command to print that config information though: `firebase setup:web`.

The problem is that it is not printing the `measurementId` field.

What should I do now?

Comment: measurementId is shows only when you activate google analytics en your project.

Answer (score 20):

In fact the `firebase setup:web` is not printing the `measurementId`. But if you refer to   [Firebase CLI reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#management-commands) you can see that this command is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Instead, use apps:sdkconfig and specify web as the
>   platform argument.

You should now use the `firebase apps:sdkconfig`. From that command you'll have the `measurementId`.

Comment: Thanks this worked. 
Make sure you run `firebase login` first.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Firebase measurementId]

In case anyone trying to find it from the Firebase web console

- it is displayed when you enable Google analytics first time for the project.
- For seeing the existing firebase configuration

Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> General -> Select your Web App -> Select 'Config'

Answer (score 4):

You need to **enable Google Analytics** first in the integration tab then you can follow Jijo John's answer.